# A library to convert ANSI escapes (terminal formatting/color codes) to HTML

Tags: html, terminal-color, ansi-escape

I'm looking for a code library that converts ANSI escape sequences into HTML color, via plain  tags or CSS. For example, something that would convert this:

```
ESC[00mESC[01;34mbinESC[00m
ESC[01;34mcodeESC[00m
ESC[01;31mdropbox-lnx.x86-0.6.404.tar.gzESC[00m
ESC[00mfooESC[00m
```

Into this:

```
<span style="color:blue">bin</span>
<span style="color:blue">code</span>
<span style="color:red">dropbox-lnx.x86-0.6.404.tar.gz</span>
foo
```

Converting breaks into <br/> isn't necessary, it's just the escape codes that I don't know. I could hack it together myself, but I'd probably miss something important like underlines or mess up how background colors work. I'd rather just sit on top of someone else's code.

Does such a tool (command line linux) or library (perl, python, or ruby preferably) exist?

Comment: Great question and a valuable set of answers!

Comment: [ANSI4J](https://github.com/PavelKastornyy/ansi4j) is a Java library that parses ANSI functions and can generate CSS declarations. So, we have separately text and CSS styles for this text.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There seems to be [an HTML::FromANSI Perl module](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::FromANSI).

Comment: this module installs ansi2html that you can pipe input.
`ls --color | ansi2html -p > my_web_page.html`

`ls --color | ansi2html > my_snpipet_code-no_header-footer.html`

BUT I prefer the default output from [ansi2html.sh from pixelbeat](http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/ansi2html.sh)

Answer (score 107):

`aha` is a C-language program, available in an Ubuntu package, at http://ziz.delphigl.com/tool_aha.php or on github https://github.com/theZiz/aha, that takes an input with terminal colors by pipe or file and puts a (w3c conform) HTML-File in stdout. Example:

```
ls --color=always | aha > ls-output.htm
```

or

```
ls --color=always | aha --black > ls-output.htm
```

for a terminal-like look with black background.

Compile it by "make" and put it where ever you want.

It would be great to get Feedback. ;-)

Comment: IcanDivideBy0 missed something: the "german link" in Alexander Matthes' post remains valid. The orig post has an erroneous ' ' before "ziz" in it; use http://ziz.delphigl.com/tool_aha.php Further, Alexander's link points to: - source at http://ziz.delphigl.com/data/aha-src-0.4.4.tar.gz, and - other debian packages at http: //packages.debian.org/search?keywords=aha *(remove the space (' ') added after ':', as I don't have priveleges to include more than 2 links per post.)*

Comment: There is an ubuntu package for aha

Comment: Just wanted to note for others that the github repo for this app compiles and runs without problem on os x. :)

Comment: yep, compiled with a pretty oddball version of gcc that i have to use at work. nice and simple.

Comment: I just added a [Homebrew Pull Request for aha](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/26921). If it gets accepted, installing aha will be a simple `brew update && brew install aha` on Macs.

Comment: Exactly what I needed for a project!

Comment: Seems to handle only 16 colors, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 24):

Mature Python library and command line tool which is still maintained: [pycontribs/ansi2html](https://github.com/pycontribs/ansi2html)

Alternatively, for the Bourne shell: [ansi2html.sh](https://github.com/pixelb/scripts/blob/master/scripts/ansi2html.sh)

Comment: "Inspired by and developed off of the work of pixelbeat and blackjack". I like this one better, and the -i option is great :)

Comment: Great! Both handle 256 colors too. Upvoted.

Comment: The pixelbeat [ansi2html.sh](https://github.com/pixelb/scripts/blob/master/scripts/ansi2html.sh) worked nicely for me!

Comment: Not limited to Bourne anymore and deb, yum, apt packages available: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ansi2html/1.0.7