# How can I syntax highlight the output from the exec() function in PHP?

Tags: php, shell, syntaxhighlighter, passthru

I'm fetching output from the [`exec()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and I would like to have some syntax highlighting in the results.

### Raw output

Current output is raw:

```
* [35mmanu[m/etc/init.d/mast: line 105: /var/log/mast/mast-all.log: Permission denied
```

Text such as `[35m` are color [highlighting in shell context](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt#List_of_colors_for_prompt_and_Bash).

### Goal

I want to do it in HTML, I already have a colored shell script.

[image: highlighted syntax]

Comment: Where do you want to do it? Command line or HTML?

Comment: What code do you currently use? Is the control code there? How do you output the value from exec?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I want to do it in HTML, I alrady have a colored shell script.

Comment: @MatsLindh here is my code to output the results: https://gist.github.com/edouard-lopez/a68b9bc8e6f2931db214 pretty straightforward at the moment

Comment: See also [Converting ANSI escape sequences to HTML using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375683/converting-ansi-escape-sequences-to-html-using-php)

Comment: Sorry, got the dupe wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question [A library to convert ANSI escapes (terminal formatting/color codes) to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2975843/802365) has an answer to this question.

### Solution

**[aha](http://explainshell.com/explain/1/aha)** is a *Ansi* to *HTML* Adapter written in *C*. It's available in an Ubuntu 
package and on github [theZiz/aha](https://github.com/theZiz/aha).

My code is then simply:

```php
   exec("$command | aha", $output, $exitCode);
   foreach($output as $k => $line) {
       if ($line == '1') { continue; }
       echo "$line";
   }
```

### Description

```
   aha takes SGR-colored Input and prints W3C conform HTML-Code.
   aha reads the Input from a file or stdin and writes HTML-Code to stdout.
```

There is some [nice options](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/aha.1.html):

- `--black` , `-b`: Black Background and white "standard color"
- `--word-wrap` , `-w`: Wrap long lines in the html file. This works with CSS3 supporting browsers as well as many older ones.
- `--no-header` , `-n`: Don't include header into generated HTML, useful for inclusion in full HTML files.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it in pure PHP thanks to symfony. using [ansi-to-html](https://github.com/sensiolabs/ansi-to-html) library. 
It has no dependency, so it is not required to use symfony.

You can install it manually by coping `SensioLabs\AnsiConverter\AnsiToHtmlConverte.php`in your source folder or using composer 
    composer require sensiolabs/ansi-to-html

After that just a

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use SensioLabs\AnsiConverter\AnsiToHtmlConverter;

$converter = new AnsiToHtmlConverter();

$html = $converter->convert($ansi);
```