# How can I convert the output of `git diff --color-words` to HTML?

Tags: git, diff

For working with text that is prose, stored in plain text, I really like the output of `git diff --color-words`, but I don't like the way it is dependent on ANSI terminal escape sequences.  I'd like to get output that I can use to turn into HTML, some kind of user-friendly raw character display, or to generate statistics on the differences between the two files.

I prefer Perl (including CPAN), but would settle for pretty much anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245121/a-library-to-convert-ansi-escapes-terminal-formatting-color-codes-to-html) asks about converting ANSI escape sequences into HTML color directives, and the accepted answer is a link to [the Perl module `HTML::FromANSI`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::FromANSI), in CPAN.

Comment: this seems like a bit of a dirty hack, but it'll do if git, perl and the distributed lib are requirements for my end users