# Coloured Git diff to HTML

Tags: html, git, colors, diff, terminal

I enjoy using `git diff --color-words` to clearly see the words that have changed in a file:

[image: Screenshot]

However I want to share that diff with someone without git or a colour terminal for that matter. So does anyone know of a tool or trick that can convert **colour escaped terminal output** into HTML?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

```bash
wget "http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/ansi2html.sh" -O /tmp/ansi2html.sh
chmod +x /tmp/ansi2html.sh
git diff --color-words --no-index orig.txt edited.txt | \
/tmp/ansi2html.sh > 2beshared.html
```

What I really needed was an [ANSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to HTML converter. And I found a very decent one on http://www.pixelbeat.org/.

NOTE: You might not see any coloration unless you include `--color` or `--color-words`, probably because piping causes git diff to exclude colors.

NOTE 2: You may need to install gnu sed and awk, especially if you're on a Mac. Do so with `brew install gnu-sed gawk`. You may need to add them to your path manually, too, e.g. with `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/gnu-sed/4.2.2/bin/gsed /usr/local/bin/`.

Comment: Glad you like it :) You can see some example usage here: http://www.pixelbeat.org/docs/terminal_colours/

Comment: Two other duplicate questions, answered by "use the HTML::FromANSI Perl module on CPAN": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425738/how-can-i-convert-the-output-of-git-diff-color-words-to-html , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245121/a-library-to-convert-ansi-escapes-terminal-formatting-color-codes-to-html

Comment: I have been looking, for days, for something like this to generate automatic LaTex diffs. This is my best find of the week. Thanks!

Comment: Does this still work? I'm getting some sed errors: sed: 2: "
s#\x1b[^\x1b]*\x1b\\## ...": bad flag in substitute command: '#'
sed: 15: "
# escape HTML
s#\&#\&a ...": bad flag in substitute command: '#'
sed: 43: "
:ansi_to_span # replac ...": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)

Comment: the only problem is even though you have created an HTML diff file you cannot send it in email with colour formatting using python

Comment: I've found that using this script I've been getting the best layout using: `git diff f0f7dfb4 43f7949 --color | ./ansi2html.sh > changes.html`

Comment: Doesn't work with BSD sed (Mac OS X), I installed GNU sed http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/how-to-replace-mac-os-x-utilities-with-gnu-core-utilities . Works great !

Comment: Latex users sometimes have very long lines. If you add | fold -w 80 -s | as part of your pipe it will wordwrap the colored lines.

Comment: @hendry is there any alternative to this script on windows ?

Comment: Just install cygwin on Windows perhaps?

Comment: I can confirm this works using cygwin (well at least on my setup, but a quick look at the script I do not see it using any non-standard commands).

Comment: For dark background use : `/tmp/ansi2html.sh --bg=dark`

Comment: depends on having `gawk` (which I guess everyone except me does).

Answer (score 12):

download diff2html, extract it and convert diff to html with this command:

```
$ diff2html file1.txt file2.txt > diff-demo1.htm
```

There is more ... take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641055/diff-to-html-diff2html-program) question.

**Or** after gitting:

```
git diff --color-words --no-index orig.txt /tmp/edited.txt > myfile
```

download both ansifilter from [this](http://www.andre-simon.de/) location. and use this command to convert myfile to html format

```
ansifilter -i myfile -H -o myfile2.html
```

so ... this is exactly what you want ;)

Comment: http://www.flickr.com/photos/hendry/4250699527/

I am not accepting `diff2html` because it looks AWFUL.

Comment: That looks awful too. I want it to look like my terminal screenshot above.

Comment: I still don't like it. I am convince I need to write some sort of ANSI escape to HTML convertor.

Comment: Thanks very much for trying to help Michel. You were pipped to the post. :)

Comment: diff2html is a great script, that can be easily modified to produced any results.

Answer (score 12):

I just found [aha](https://github.com/theZiz/aha) in debian repositories; it's trivial:

```
git diff --color | aha > white.html          # white background
git diff --color | aha --black > black.html  # black background
git diff --color | aha --pink > pink.html    # pink background
```

Its tiny download size (<20KB) got me curious, so I peeked at its source: it is a [self-contained C file](https://github.com/theZiz/aha/blob/master/aha.c) with only 4 includes: `errno.h`, `stdlib.h`, `stdio.h` and `string.h`, and depends on only libc. Beauty!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to see **clean diffs** with **line similarity matching**, **better word comparison**, **syntax highlight** and more check out [diff2html](https://github.com/rtfpessoa/diff2html) which is very *customizable* git diff to HTML presenter.

To use it on the command line you can check [diff2html-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/diff2html-cli) which is a simple CLI written in Node.js.

So you can share your diffs with colleagues it integrates with [diffy.org](http://diffy.org/).

Check out a diff sample [here](https://diff2html.xyz/demo.html?matching=none&matchWordsThreshold=0.25&maxLineLengthHighlight=10000&diffStyle=word&renderNothingWhenEmpty=0&matchingMaxComparisons=2500&maxLineSizeInBlockForComparison=200&outputFormat=line-by-line&drawFileList=1&synchronisedScroll=1&highlight=1&fileListToggle=1&fileListStartVisible=0&smartSelection=1&diff=https://github.com/rtfpessoa/diff2html/pull/106).

Comment: Thanks, it is a great tool. It would be nice if it would be added support for diffs made under Windows (after the --- and +++ lines the paths are quoted).

Comment: It is possible to install diff2html in any other way than via `npm`?

Comment: @dokaspar not really. You can run the js directly but in the end npm is the only package manager supported.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know any tool to do exactly what you want. But here's a piece of code I often use to output html formatted colored diff: [simplediff](http://github.com/paulgb/simplediff)

It's available in PHP and Python. The output tags the differences using `<del>` and `<ins>` tags so you can easily color them using CSS.

Comment: It's a shame there isn't a simple wrapper around simple diff to make coloured diffs (either html or in terminal).

Answer (score 2):

You may want to checkout the github project [rmed](https://github.com/roubles/rmed), which provides a command line tool, that generates static shareable html diffs using vimdiff.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a perl script to generate html table for the git diff. To use this script first you have to collect the diff by using git diff sha1s... > diff.file, then run diff2html.pl diff.file.
Visit:

http://kernel-demystified.com/forum/index.php/topic,23.msg28.html#new

Comment: `Unable to determine IP address from host name kernel-demystified.com`

Answer (score 1):

when I use git bash, if you use `git show` you only need to copy and paste what is shown in the console and it copies the colours correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old. However, if you're using PHP I've just shared a simple renderer that adds some style to the native git diff console output: https://github.com/nrctkno/git-diff-renderer .