# Git word-diff to html

Tags: python, html, git

how would you convert the output of `git diff --word-diff` to html (using Python preferably)?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013091/coloured-diff-to-html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053657/git-diff-to-html?

Comment: Yes, but word-diff seems less hacky to work with (compared to color-words), especially with the porcelain output mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe a call to aha (a tool that converts colored terminal text to html).
Something like this:

```
git diff --word-diff | aha
```

If you using debian, you can download it from this link: http://packages.debian.org/sid/aha
Hope it helps.

Comment: Even though `git diff --word-diff` displays with colour, I had trouble getting `aha` to add the colour until I did `git diff --word-diff --color | aha`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [dvicino's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9076683/5181692), using `aha` works well.  In my case, I needed to additionally use `--color` with `git diff --word-diff`:

```bash
git diff --word-diff --color | aha
```

The need to use `--color` is a little perplexing, because `git diff --word-diff` makes coloured output without `--color`.  But apparently the output isn't sufficiently [ANSI-coded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) for `aha` to "adapt" it to HTML.

In my specific case, I'm using something more like the following, and it works exactly as expected.

```bash
git diff --word-diff --color [revisionhash] | aha --black --word-wrap > diff.html
```

(I'm adding a full answer in addition to my comment, because I was unable to find any answers that indicted that `--color` is needed.  Maybe it's a system-specific thing, but perhaps others will find this useful.)