# Django two files upload for difference

Tags: python, django, difference, delta, difflib

I have already posted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26776003/how-to-use-htmldiff-in-django-to-show-difference-of-two-uploaded-files

However, I want to know if there is an easy way to upload a couple of files and submit which shows the differences between those two files in the next page. I made it work in the link above, but it won't work for large files like 4/ 5 MB.

I desperately need to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: What does "won't work" mean?

Comment: It would just keep loading the next page and show nothing. When I run the same script for diff in a .py file and run it, the same thing happens in the terminal also. The cursor keeps blinking but it won't show the result. So I'm guessing instead of max_file_size there is something wrong with my program.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running a different diff tool on the server and just dumping the HTML output? diff2html comes to mind, maybe see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2013826/3586654) answer for some more details?

Answer (score 0):

> it won't work for large files like 4/5 MB

The problem you might be having is the `client_max_body_size` or equivalent parameter in your web server's config. For example for `nginx` you'll find this in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/yoursite`.

```
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name yoursite.example;

        client_max_body_size 2M;
```

Comment: I can upload the files, but the script of difflib doesn't finish running and doesn't display the result!