# GitHub commit emailer

Tags: email, github, version-control

I want to send email to all the developers for every commit made in repository. I have explored GitHub default email service but its not useful as it does not include code diff of the commit. Is there any other way to send out coloured html formatted email for every commit push to the server.

Answer (score 2):

Since the [GitHub email notification service](https://help.github.com/articles/receiving-email-notifications-for-pushes-to-a-repository/) isn't enough, you can use a simple [git push webhook](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent), and listen to it.

On a server set to listen to that push event, do a git fetch, and for each commit, [generate an html page with the colored diff content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2013091/6309).
Then send the email from that server with the right content.

Comment: GitHub is so widely used, are there any opensource solutions for doing this. I found gitdub and git-notifier but they don't send coloured emails I think(have to confirm).

Comment: @akshay202 I agree. My solution is still using a GitHUb feature (webhook), but requires a listener of your own.