# Is there a way to create MS Word style track changes for two text file versions?

Tags: git, ms-word, markdown, change-tracking, asciidoc

When writing documents it can be important to have a track-changes file available for reviewers. Non-technical reviewers are used to Microsoft Word's track changes feature, where the additions/deletions/modifications are marked up in the working file. I can't find a way to create an equivalent change markup file when working with text-based files such as Markdown or AsciiDoc. Text compare applications, such as Araxis Merge, create various types of report files but nothing like Word's track changes. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Any version control system should be able to do this. You just need to learn how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

In `git`, the [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) command will produce comparisons between different commits (i.e. recorded moments in time), different branches of the same code base, and even the differences between two separate files. `git merge` allows for interactively merging 'conflicting' versions of a document. Very powerful, but nothing like 'track changes' in terms of user interface.

Until you refine your question to a specific piece of software, you may have better luck posting to [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). The more detail you can include on your *specific needs* (user base, interface, specific features, etc), the better a reception you'll get there.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Chris. I did explore git diff after posting my question. While I can create a diff on the commandline and in Git GUI with character level differences that are similar to Word's track changes, there doesn't seem to be a way to make a file with the changes that can be shared with others. I'd like to be able to make a PDF or other file that I can email to someone to show the differences. When I use git diff --color-words=. > result.diff, the result has codes that need an interpreter to display the colors. How can I make a PDF that shows the color coding?

Comment: @markbez, I don't have a PDF solution for you, but this thread covers [converting diffs to HTML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013091/coloured-git-diff-to-html). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Chris!  Your link gave me what I needed. I used ANSIFilter to create a change markup HTML file, which I can then convert to PDF. Once I worked out how ANSI escape codes work, I found I can just use find and replace in Sublime text to convert the escape codes to HTML span tags with CSS styling, and surrounded with +++ for passthrough in the AsciiDoc file. It's fast enough to do and creates a perfect output for revieweres.