# How to convert Linux's shell output to HTML?

Tags: html, linux, shell

Is there any easy way to convert bash output to HTML? For example, if I have some colorized output in bash (something like `htop`), how can I convert it to HTML, with corresponding stylings/tags/css/etc.

Comment: What would the conversion results look like? There is no recognizable structure here that could be converted into HTML tags. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Your data seems to be full of ANSI control sequences. Is that intentional?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245121/a-library-to-convert-ansi-escapes-terminal-formatting-color-codes-to-html

Comment: If you are using Konsole terminal emulator you can File -> Save Output As... then choose File type: HTML document, to save everything to HTML

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There's `ansifilter` plus some tools like `highlight` will produce colorized html from plain text such as source files.

Both available [here](http://www.andre-simon.de/).

Comment: This is exactly what I want ... ansifilter -i file -H -o file.html

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you need to pipe the result through a tool like [ansi2html](http://search.cpan.org/~autrijus/HTML-FromANSI-1.01/script/ansi2html).

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in @eli's answer, you can use `script` to capture the colored output to a file.

You can then convert the output to HTML with `aha`, the "[Ansi HTML Adapter](https://github.com/theZiz/aha)", which should be available in your distribution's repositories: `apt install aha` or `yum install aha` for Debian-based or Redhat-based distributions.

If you want to capture only a **single command**, use the `-c` option:

```
script -c "grep --color ..."
```

This will save the output to a file named `typescript` in your current directory.

To save to a different file, add the file name at the end:

```
script -c "grep --color ..." my_grep_colored_output
```

See `man script` for other options.

To capture **several commands** from an interactive session, just start `script` without a command, and enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> to exit script when done.

To just **view the file in color**, use `less -R`.

To **convert it to HTML** with `aha` :

```
aha -s -f typescript > output.html
```

or

```
aha -s < typescript > output.html
```

The `-s` option makes it write a style sheet in the html header instead of using inline styles through the file. That makes it easier to change colors if some background/foreground combinations turn out hard to read in a browser.

Comment: `aha` did the trick for me, and was available in the debian repositories, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Without any pretty-printing, the simplest thing you can always do is to escape everything that needs escaping, and wrap a basic HTML shell around (the following should be valid minimal HTML5). For example, get a hold of fastesc: http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/fastesc/, and that wrap it into an HTML shell.

If you want to preserve the ANSI magic, then you need to convert that to HTML, perhaps with  http://ansi-sys.rubyforge.org/

And then do something like this, depending on your needs:

```
require 'ansisys'


def ansi_escape(string)
    terminal = AnsiSys::Terminal.new
    terminal.echo(string)
    terminal.render 
end

def to_html(string)
    %Q{ <!DOCTYPE html>
        <title>Converted to html</title>
        <pre>
        #{ansi_escape(string)}
        </pre>
    } 
end
```

Comment: This probably still needs HTML escaping.

Answer (score 2):

1.) check that `ansifilter` and `script` programs are installed

2.) `script -c 'ansible-playbook -i /tmp/or/some /tmp/other/command.yml' -O /tmp/myTypescriptOutput.file`

(`script` writes the [output of a command to a file](https://superuser.com/questions/352697/preserve-colors-while-piping-to-tee/751809#751809) in typescript notation)

3.) 
convert to html, e.g. to view with your browser:

`ansifilter -i /tmp/myTypescriptOutput.file -H -o output.html`

convert to rtf, e.g. to view with libreoffice or word

`ansifilter -i /tmp/myTypescriptOutput.file -R -o output.rtf`

see `man ansifilter` for other options (latex, tex, svg, pangot, txt, ...)

(additional, if `highlight` is installed:

`highlight /tmp/myTypescriptOutput.file --force`

... this will print the saved-shell output in color, like if it was executed at first time)