# difference between 'cat -A' in bash and 'set list' in vim

Tags: bash, vim, cat

File is [bidd.nus.edu.sg/group/TTD/filedownload.asp?file=flatfiles/drug-disease_TTD2013.txt](http://bidd.nus.edu.sg/group/TTD/filedownload.asp?file=flatfiles/drug-disease_TTD2013.txt)

When I use `cat -A drug-disease_TTD2013.txt` it shows `^M$` in the end of each line. In vim, `set list` and it shows only `$` without `^M`.

`sed 's/\r//' drug-disease_TTD2013.txt >1.t` can make it the same. but I do not know why? (revised)

Also in manual of cat: `-v use ^ and M- notation, except for LFD and TAB` What's the meaning of that?

not the same situation in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501288/different-show-between-cat-and-vim)

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a little output ?

Comment: You sure `sed 's/\r//' drug-disease_TTD2013.txt` actually modified the file? Perhaps you meant `sed -i 's/\r//' drug-disease_TTD2013.txt`? Also try `dos2unix`.

Comment: `vim` probably recognizes the file as having DOS line endings, and so `$` here represents `\r\n`, not just `\n`. `cat` is showing the literal bytes.

Comment: @konsolebox, Yes, you're right.Actually, I mean `sed 's/\r//' drug-disease_TTD2013.txt > 1.t` . @chepner, is there `^M$` in vim in some situation? (Maybe file from OS X's `\r`?, I'm not sure, just cannot find this kind of file this moment). I encountered that issue some times.

Comment: @ZhilongJIA: If you open the file with `ff=unix`, the file is in dos format and list is set, there will be `^M$` in vim.

Comment: @JanHudec , @IngoKarket Actually, before this post, I did not know the `ff=unix` option of vim. Usually, I open file with vim directly, like `vim 1.t`, When I want to check the separator, I will use `:set list`. So, it should be that I open a file and `:set list`, then I find there are `^M$` directly.(Maybe only open a file, it will show `^M` because I forget it.) When `echo 'fsl\tfdlj\r\n' > 1.t`, in vim, it directly shows the `^M`. But `vim drug-disease_TTD2013.txt`, it shows no `^M` without the `set list`. How strange! Why? Thank you.

Comment: @ZhilongJIA: The `set ff` will only affects how the file is _saved_, but if the file was already loaded, the `^M`s are not in memory already, so they won't appear. You have to use the `e ++ff` command to reload the file. In the echo case, `echo` adds one more `^J` itself, so there are two newlines and only the first one is preceded by `^M`. In which case vim will not conclude it is in dos format.

Comment: @JanHudec ,  Thank you. `^J` should be `$`.

Comment: @ZhilongJIA: In `^` notation, line feed is `^J`. `$` is marker for the end of line, but not really name for the control character. Of course, being unix, `^J` terminates lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In vim, type

```
:set ff?
```

I suppose it will respond with

```
fileformat=dos
```

That means that the end of line is `␍␊` (`^M^J`, `\r\n`) rather than just `␊` (`^J`, `\n`). This is autodetected by vim when opening the file if all newlines are consistently the same two-byte sequence.

To re-open the file in unix mode, just type:

```
:e ++ff=unix
```

now it will show the `^M` characters. It will show them even without `list` option, because they now are in the buffer as regular characters.

Comment: Please see my comment in my question @chepner. Additionally, Also in manual of cat: `-v use ^ and M- notation, except for LFD and TAB` What's the meaning of that? Thank you.

Comment: @ZhilongJIA: `^`-notation represents characters 0 to 31 as `^@` (=0), `^A` to `^Z`, `^[`, `^\`, `^]`, `^^` and `^_`. `M-`-notation represents bytes 128 to 255 as `M-` and character with value 128 less.

Answer (score 1):

`cat` is a Unix tool, and as such expects the platform's line endings, LF (`^J`).

Vim is multi-platform and detects the (consistent) use of different line endings. Your file apparently has Windows-style CR-LF line endings, so Vim just shows the `$` sigil.

To change that, you can explicitly specify the fileformat on opening:

```
$ vim -c 'set list' -c 'edit ++fileformat=unix drug-disease_TTD2013.txt'
```

If you're just on Linux / Unix systems, it's probably easiest to convert the source file to Unix-style line endings, using either `sed`, `dos2unix`, or Vim.

Comment: Thank you. `sed`, `dos2unix` and `vim` can handle it. Another matter, please see my comment in my question @chepner.