# Filter special chars such as color codes from shell output

Tags: python, shell

I ran shell commands in python, logged their outputs into files and finally showed on a web page. however the color style chars of command outputs were also logged. is there a way to filter out the color style chars or display them correctly on web pages? Many thanks!

Output log:

```
" 22200K .......\u001b[0m\u001b[91m... .......... ...\u001b[0m\u001b[91m.\u001b[0m\u001b[91m...... .........\u001b[0m\u001b[91m.\u001b[0m\u001b[91m \u001b[0m\u001b[91m.\u001b[0m\u001b[91m.\u001b[0m\u001b[91m.\u001b[0m\u001b[91m.\u001b[0m\u001b[91m...... 50% 28.6K 12m55s"
```

the real text:

```
[INFO][88] 22250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 50% 35.8K 12m53s
```

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2033268/3001761

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the unlikely case when you have xterm256 color codes as well, this will filter both 'normal' ansi and xterm256 ansi codes:

```
import re
print(re.sub(r'\x1b(\[.*?[@-~]|\].*?(\x07|\x1b\\))', '', a))
```

or in a slightly less obfuscated and more readable form:

```
'(' + CSI + '.*?' + CMD + '|' + OSC + '.*?' + '(' + ST + '|' + BEL + ')' + ')'
```

Complete code with tests:

```
import re

tests = [
    u"22200K .......\u001b[0m\u001b[91m... .......... ...\u001b[0m\u001b[91m.\u001b[0m\u001b[91m...... .........\u001b[0m\u001b[91m.\u001b[0m\u001b[91m \u001b[0m\u001b[91m.\u001b[0m\u001b[91m.\u001b[0m\u001b[91m.\u001b[0m\u001b[91m.\u001b[0m\u001b[91m...... 50% 28.6K 12m55s",
    u"=\u001b[m=",
    u"-\u001b]23\u0007-",
]

def trim_ansi(a):
    ESC = r'\x1b'
    CSI = ESC + r'\['
    OSC = ESC + r'\]'
    CMD = '[@-~]'
    ST = ESC + r'\\'
    BEL = r'\x07'
    pattern = '(' + CSI + '.*?' + CMD + '|' + OSC + '.*?' + '(' + ST + '|' + BEL + ')' + ')'
    return re.sub(pattern, '', a)

for t in tests:
    print(trim_ansi(t))
```

As a one-liner:

```bash
ls --color | python -c 'import re, sys; sys.stdout.write(re.sub(r"\x1b(\[.*?[@-~]|\].*?(\x07|\x1b\\))", "", sys.stdin.read()))'
```

Answer (score 5):

This should work in most cases:

```
import re
print(re.sub(u'\u001b\[.*?[@-~]', '', a))
```

**Update**

> Escape sequences start with the character ESC (ASCII decimal 27/hex 0x1B/octal 033). For two character sequences, the second character is in the range ASCII 64–95 (@ to _).
> However, most of the sequences are more than two characters, and start with the characters ESC and [ (left bracket). This sequence is called CSI for Control Sequence Introducer (or Control Sequence Initiator). The final character of these sequences is in the range ASCII 64–126 (@ to ~).
> (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

**Update2**

With the following 'a.py':

```
import sys, re

for line in sys.stdin:
    sys.stdout.write(re.sub(u'\u001b\[.*?[@-~]', '', line))
```

this works smoothly for me:

```
ls --color | python a.py
```

Comment: thanks, jettico! Actually I am hoping a common way for all colorful shell outputs. The example I described in my question is just one of them.

Comment: This is a quick and not at all universal solution, but it is supposed to cover most ANSI codes used in practice. Give an example of the codes that this chunk didn't filter and I'll integrate them too. Or use a full-fledged solution as suggested by @jonrsharpe

Comment: Can you give an example of how it doesn't work for you? In the Update2 I gave an example of how it works for me.

Comment: tried again in a python script on your update #2. works for me now! Many thanks!  I will try it with anther more complex cases. BTW, this code re.sub('r'\x1b(\[.*?[@-~]|\].*?(\x07|\x1b\\))', '', a) has a typo. there is redundant single quotation in 'r'

Comment: Fixed, thanks. You could as well try the recipe linked in my third answer, but chances are it wont work for you since it only deals with 'normal' ansi codes.

Comment: I guess the right single quotation should be at the right side of r.  it should be r' other than 'r

Comment: )))) That's what happens when you do several things at once.

Answer (score 1):

This python recipe transforms ansi codes to html:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577349-convert-a-transcript-with-ansi-escape-sequences-to/

Answer (score -1):

You can simply pipe the output through `strings` to remove any non-printable characters:

```
./some-script | strings
```

Comment: This doesn't work: `ls --color |strings` leaves all color codes as is, omitting only the first ESC symbol in them.