# Java Multi-Line Console Input and Cursor Handling

Tags: java, terminal, console, console-input

The following problem arised while building a REPL console application for a programming language. Essentially, the language relies on you being able to write multiple lines of text. However, the `ENTER` key should also be usable to evaluate an expression.

```
> 1 + 1<enter>
int int1 = 2
> <cursor>
```

To allow multi-line input, I am using an algorithm that counts the number of parentheses, braces, brackets and quotes, so if either of them are unbalanced, it inserts a newline:

```
> if (int1 < 3) {<enter>
|     println "ok"<enter>
|     }<enter>
ok
> <cursor>
```

The main problem with this approach is that as soon as I press enter on a line, that line cannot be edited anymore. Repeatedly pressing `BACKSPACE` at the `}` symbol will first delete it and then stay at that position without removing the newline and allowing me to delete the `println` line. This makes programs very error-prone and editing very tedious.

Another problem is the fact that I can't even use the cursor in some consoles (like the Mac Terminal). The console will just show ANSI control codes in that event.

---

Is there a way to solve both problems, perhaps by introducing custom cursor handling to my REPL frontend? How much access does the JVM give me to the enclosing console? Can I force consoles to redirect all key presses to the program? And, do I have to use different techniques for different IDE consoles / terminals / Operating Systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not "the JVM", but the unsophisticated code of JavaRepl.  Console input (see the [source](https://github.com/albertlatacz/java-repl/blob/master/src/javarepl/Repl.java#L115)) is just reading *lines* from the standard input:

```
private static Mapper<Sequence<String>, String> readFromConsole() {
    return new Mapper<Sequence<String>, String>() {
        private final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        public String call(Sequence<String> lines) throws Exception {
            return reader.readLine();
        }
    };
}
```

[`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) really does not do a lot.  Its documentation is also not helpful.  A description on [TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/bufferedreader_readline.htm) helps;

> The java.io.BufferedReader.readline() method read a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

To improve JavaRepl as you would like, it would have to be modified to (at least) allow treating the escape sequences sent by left-arrow and keypad-delete the same as "backspace" (actually delete).  It is doable (but perhaps not what the developers of JavaRepl intend: compatibility with old versions of Java is likely a consideration).  Even the "newer" [`Console`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) class from Java6 is documented without hinting that it is more than a modest reworking of `BufferedReader` to help with password prompts.

For reading escape sequences, see

- [Java framework for reading / writing ANSI escape-sequenced character streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520116/java-framework-for-reading-writing-ansi-escape-sequenced-character-streams)
- [Clear the console and control attributes](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0047.html)

To get multi-line editing, another step would be needed to change its interface to allow retrieving prior lines and editing those.  I think that is beyond the scope of JavaRepl's design (but you might suggest it to the developers).