# JTextPane output weird console characters

Tags: java, linux, swing, swingworker

I was trying to run console command in Kali linux, but the output are just weird when i pipe it to the `JTextPane`. When I diplay it on the output console of Netbean it was fine.

Command that I'm trying to run: `wifite -e Experiment -c 1`

[image]

code:

```
    public cracker(JTextPane aOutputPane)
      {
       super();
        mOutputPane = aOutputPane;
  }
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground() throws Exception
  {
    Process p = null;
    try
    {
        String Channel=CNinput.getText();
        String WName=WN.getText();
      p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wifite -e "+WName+" -c "+Channel);
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
      Logger.getLogger(home.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line = "";
    String output = "";
    try
    {
      while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null)
      {
        publish(line);
        output += line + "\n";
      }
    }
    cat

ch (IOException ex)
    {
      Logger.getLogger(home.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try
    {
      p.waitFor();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex)
    {
      Logger.getLogger(home.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return output;
  }
  @Override
  protected void process(java.util.List<String> aChunks)
  {
    mOutputPane.setText(null);
    final String intermediateOutput = aChunks.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    final String existingText = mOutputPane.getText();
    final String newText = existingText + "\n" + intermediateOutput;
    mOutputPane.setText(newText);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The characters are [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), intended to control the appearance of the terminal output generated by `wifite`. Among your options,

- Elide the character sequences as they arrive in your implementation of `doInBackground()`; they all start with the [`ESC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) character.
- Examine the codes and recapitulate the corresponding style in your `JTextPane`, as shown in the `StyledDocument` seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15600689/230513).
- Use a library such as the [NetBeans console](https://netbeans.org/community/sources/) or `Jansi`, cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6529009/230513).

Comment: After some googling with the thing you mentioned i find it useful, especially Jansi, is it possible to implement it to the .setText and how? I only find limited references on the system.out to AnsiConsole.systemInstall();.

Comment: I'm not sure that `Jansi` supports this usage directly, but it might be worth looking at how it does parsing. I've never needed more than a handful of `SimpleAttributeSet` instances in this context.

Comment: How can I use SimpleAttributeSet with Jtextpanel, meaning like how would I allow the console pipe output to pipe formatted text into the jtextpanel?

Comment: You'd have to parse the code and apply the corresponding `SimpleAttributeSet`; sorry, I don't know a simpler approach. Because `JTextPane ` can display (limited) HTML, you might be able to leverage `HtmlAnsiOutputStream`, but I haven't tried it.