# Save colored text to file with Ruby

Tags: html, ruby, colors

I have a script that writes colored output to the terminal via a custom module like here: [Colorized Ruby output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489183/colorized-ruby-output)

I would like to also save this output to a file in color similar to how `aha` works here: [A library to convert ANSI escapes (terminal formatting/color codes) to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245121/a-library-to-convert-ansi-escapes-terminal-formatting-color-codes-to-html)

How can I use Ruby to both output to the terminal in color and save to a file in color in html or some other markup that's easily read by non-developers.

Comment: You could use [`tee`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) to write the script's output to both, stdout and a file and convert the file afterwards as needed (e.g. via `aha`)

Comment: I was thinking about this but how could `tee` retain the colors?

Comment: Those colors are just sequences of character that are interpreted by your terminal. Just like `"\n"` – it is interpreted as a newline, but can nonetheless be written to a file.