# How to capture terminal screen output (with ansi color) to an image file?

Tags: screen-capture, ansi-escape

I tried the following command to capture the output of a command (`grep` as an example) with color. But the result is shown as `^[[01;31m^[[Ka^[[m^[[K`.

```
grep --color=always a <<< a | 
    a2ps -=book -B -q --medium=A4dj --borders=no -o out1.ps &&
    gs \
    -sDEVICE=png16m           \
    -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER \
    -dTextAlphaBits=4 -q      \
    -r300x300                 \
    -sOutputFile=out2.png out1.ps
```

Is there a way to capture the color in the image? Thanks.

Comment: [May](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70450/can-groff-create-a-ps-file-with-interpreted-ansi-escape-characters) [be](https://superuser.com/questions/552657/how-to-convert-ansi-colored-text-to-pdf) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245121/a-library-to-convert-ansi-escapes-terminal-formatting-color-codes-to-html).

Comment: It's related (and closed).  There are various ways to do what's asked, but "Is there a way" makes the question non-topical.