Git output into a document while keeping font colors?
I am trying to take the output of git log --graph --online --all --decorate and put it into a Word Document or PDF. I want to keep the font colors, for obvious reasons since a git commit tree looks messy in only black font. This is on a Windows machine.
I know you can do git blabla > filename.rtf or whatnot, but I can't find any information on how to keep those font colors. I've tried git blabla --color > filename.rtf but I can't seem to open it in any coherent encoding whether in Notepad++, Word, or anything else I have available to me. If I knew at least what the encoding --color uses, then I could work with that, but I can't seem to find that either.
I am on an air-gapped work PC so I am limited to what software is available to me. The git is hosted locally too so I don't have access to Gitlab and whatnot.

https://superuser.com/questions/552657/how-to-convert-ansi-colored-text-to-pdf

@jthill An answer there has a link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245121/a-library-to-convert-ansi-escapes-terminal-formatting-color-codes-to-html :-)
